# Select all columns from table which is a result of joining two tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm wondering if it's possible to select all columns belonging to one table from result table which is a join of two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE_AB 
AS (SELECT TABLE_A.*,TABLE_B.* FROM TABLE_A NATURAL JOIN TABLE_B);
```

And I'd like to `SELECT TABLE_A FROM TABLE_AB;`

Is this possible in Oracle?

Comment: No, your new table TABLE_AB is just a table with some columns, it keeps no "memory" of how it was originally created and populated.  Why would you create this TABLE_AB anyway?  Perhaps what you really want is a view?

Comment: I needed that to get all the revelant ids from table_a to delete them from table_a (delete from table_a where id in (select id from table_ab). Now I'd like to revert that and populate my table_a with deleted data. I know that I can just list all the columns in select statement, but I was wondering if there's any faster way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comment, you could create TABLE_AB like this:

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE_AB 
AS (SELECT TABLE_A.* FROM TABLE_A NATURAL JOIN TABLE_B);
```

Now it is a copy of TABLE_A but containing only the rows you want to delete.  You can reinstate those rows later using:

```
insert into table_a select * from table_ab;
```

Comment: OK you'll just have to type out the column names then.  It's only got to be done once! :-)

Comment: Yeah, that table got 65 columns. That will be painful :)

Comment: Just select and copy them from SQL Developer columns tab?  Or `select column_name from user_tables where table_name='TABLE_AB'` and edit that into the SQL you need.

Comment: oh yes, forgot about that. Thanks!